# SelectAll Textbox Text

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using these following code. I want to when I select all text in the `textbox` it tells me but I don't know why it's not working. please give me some help. Please give some code so that I can use this when I select all text in the `textbox` `text` it tells me

```
if (textBox1.SelectAll() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have selected all text in the textbox");
        }
```

It will tell me: *Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `void` and `bool`*

Comment: is a Web App or Windows Form ?

Comment: Or are you using WPF?  I think you're getting all the "it's a void function" answers you need right now. But if you want to know when all the text is selected, this is important to know.

Comment: Please dear god don't put everything in bold

Comment: `SelectAll()` is a `method` not a `bool`. So a method cannot return type `bool` because it is **NOT** a `bool`

Comment: @OutlawLemur, what?  A method can most definitely return a bool.

Comment: @Kevin Hmmm I guess I was being too broad..... `void` methods cannot return a `bool`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couldn't you simply check whether or not `TextBox.SelectionLength == TextBox.Text.Length`?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionlength.aspx

You comparison fails because you're comparing the text with the return value of the [`SelectAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectall%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method which is void(it returns nothing since it just applies the selection).

Comment: @OutlawLemur: Just rummage for links ;)

Comment: @aliprogrammer Don't forget to mark as answer, and @ TimSchmelter Yes, I wish I got paid in rep for doing that to my own answer:(

Comment: @OutlawLemur. yes. i didn't forget. i am just waiting till it let me mark as answer. it says i can mark this in 1 minute

Comment: @aliprogrammer Sorry for mistake, **SOOOOOOOOO** many people do that, but the 5-minute rule is fair

Comment: @OutlawLemur. when you told me it said i must wait for 1 minute.

Comment: @aliprogrammer Yes but there is a ~15 minute rule that you can't accept an answer yet as to not discourage people..... You were 14 minutes through that cycle

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
textBox1.SelectAll()
```

returns `nothing` or return type is `void`

just use

```
textBox1.SelectAll();
```

**If you want to check if all text is selected or not check**

```
if(textBox1.SelectedText == textBox1.Text)
{
     MessageBox.Show("You have selected all text in the textbox");
}
```

**OR**

```
if(TextBox.SelectionLength == TextBox.Text.Length)
{
     MessageBox.Show("You have selected all text in the textbox");
}
```

Comment: i want to use this in if statement

Comment: no...you just need to take out ==true, im sure youre capable of doing thta yourself without us pasting the code for you

Comment: @aliprogrammer, SelectAll doesn't return anything. Why do you think it would? What would it even mean for it to return `false`? How could it fail?

Comment: if you need it dont like that then make selectall have a return type of boolean, if it is successful make it return true else make it return false. THEN your if statement will make sence

Comment: Fairly sure he wants to trigger something when you select all text, just got his functions messed up. If you read his question, not just the code, he states this.

Comment: @RhysW seem like you didn't understand my question. i don't want to select all text. i want to when i select all text it tells me that i have selected all text

Comment: I think the asker is wanting to know if there is a way to determine when all the text has been selected, not how to select all the text

Comment: wait, you dont want to select all text? you have a method for selecting all text, and youre tellingme you dont want to select all text and saying im the one who deosnt understand?, i can see waht youre asking, and im saying selectall will never ever ever == true, when it deosnt return anything...

Comment: @RhysW, yes, you don't understand his question.

Comment: @Kevin he is asking for a way to see if his select all has been successful and if it has tell the user it was successful, i understand what he is asking thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(textBox1.SelectedText==textBox1.Text)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only use

```
textBox1.SelectAll();
```

When this method is executed all the text in text box will be selected. You don't need to compare it with `true`. [TextBox.SelectAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectall%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) return type is `void`. Comparing a boolean with void will give error off course.

Comment: seem like you didn't understand my question. i don't want to select all text. i want to when i select all text it tells me that i have selected all text

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add an event handler for the TextBox.SelectionChanged event and in it, compare the TextBox.SelectedText to the TextBox.Text

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the GotMouseCapture Event Here the code it works fine for me.

```
 private void textBox_GotMouseCapture(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox.SelectAll();
        textBox.Focus();
    }
```